# Magento soap api delete product using sku

Tags: magento-1.8, api, soap

I have a bridge built between two applications, where products are getting dumped into magento. I am using Magento SOAP API to add/update/delete products, but i need to do delete product using SKU and not product id..Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hear the Code to remove the Product Based on SKU

**Request Example SOAP V1**

```
 $client = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/soap/?wsdl');

 // If somestuff requires api authentification,
 // then get a session token
 $session = $client->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');
 $result = $client->call($session, 'catalog_product.delete', '1');
 var_dump($result);

 // If you don't need the session anymore
 //$client->endSession($session);
```

**Request Example SOAP V2**

```
 $proxy = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/v2_soap/?wsdl'); // TODO : change url
 $sessionId = $proxy->login('apiUser', 'apiKey'); // TODO : change login and pwd if necessary

 $result = $proxy->catalogProductDelete($sessionId, '6');
 var_dump($result);
```

Please see the Image for Request and Response Data

[image]

For More Reference Please Check This [Link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.delete.html).

Comment: yep that was obvious! thx..

Comment: Hi, what about product resources like "media files" - Are they also deleted from DB and/or filesystem ? Do you have any experiences about this topic ? Regards